# Kernel Driver Not Detected by Apps in Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, driver, android-source

I'm compiling Android 11 on a development board with an RK3568, and everything is working fine. I have an accelerometer sensor that was pre-configured on the board and is functioning as expected; I can see it from the sensor test app. Now, I'm trying to add a light sensor. The driver compiles and loads successfully, and I can see the logs via dmesg:

```
[    5.295697] light_stk3410 3-0048: sensor_register_device: ls_stk3410, id = 70
[    5.295731] i2c i2c-3: sensor_probe: ls_stk3410,000000005ff24252
[    5.295769] light_stk3410 3-0048: sensor_chip_init:ls_stk3410:devid=0x0,ops=0x00000000f42f982d
[    5.295779] stk3410 init
[    5.295781] stk3410 active
[    5.296191] light_stk3410 3-0048: sensor_irq_init:use polling,delay=30 ms
[    5.296326] light_stk3410 3-0048: sensor_misc_device_register:miscdevice: lightsensor
[    5.296341] light_stk3410 3-0048: sensor_probe:initialized ok,sensor name:ls_stk3410,type:5,id=70\x0a
```

However, when I run the sensor test app, it says I have no light sensor installed. I suspect I need to add some sort of definition or notify Android that a light sensor is present, beyond just the driver level. Can anyone assist me with this?

Here are all the modifications I've made that are functioning correctly; I've configured the file that tells the board that the sensor is installed on the i2c port "kernel/arch/arm64/boot/dts/rockchip/rk3568-evb.dtsi":

```
ls_stk3410: light@48 {
        compatible = "ls_stk3410";
        status = "okay";
        reg = <0x48>;
        type = <SENSOR_TYPE_LIGHT>;
        irq_enable = <0>;
        als_threshold_high = <100>;
        als_threshold_low = <10>;
        als_ctrl_gain = <2>; /* 0:x1 1:x4 2:x16 3:x64 */
        poll_delay_ms = <100>;
};
```

I've also enabled it in "device/rockchip/common/BoardConfig.mk":

```
BOARD_LIGHT_SENSOR_SUPPORT ?= true
```

I've tried both static and dynamic driver linking (just like I did with the accelerometer), adding this line to the end of BoardConfig.mk to specify to load it:

```
BOARD_VENDOR_KERNEL_MODULES +=
kernel/drivers/input/sensors/accel/sc7a20.ko \
kernel/drivers/input/sensors/lsensor/ls_stk3410.ko
```

And adding to init.rc:

```
on early-init
    exec u:r:vendor_modprobe:s0 -- /vendor/bin/modprobe -a -d \
        /vendor/lib/modules sc7a20.ko /vendor/lib/modules ls_stk3410.ko
```

Whether I use static or dynamic linking, the driver loads fine, but I can only see the accelerometer in apps.

What I need to know is why the module seems to work fine, just like the accelerometer, but the applications can't see it. Do I need to modify some other file?

Comment: I think you need to add a sensor hal as well or modify the Lights hal to add support for this driver?

Comment: do you know how to do it?.. can't find tutorials for this king of things...

Comment: This is quite a complicated part. Not just a one day job :) I can only direct you to some resources. I am not an expert myself. Please read about the Android sensor HAL, HIDL and how they work. Maybe you will get an overall picture.

Comment: but the light sensor is a generic sensor, not customized, I think it should be easy at HAL level, like unccoment a define or similiar

Comment: 'It' in that sentence refers to "sensor test app," obviously. I set this title before knowing that Android has a HAL layer, something Linux doesn't have, and that's why it might not be well explained; now, the tone of your message is somewhat offensive, if you know so much maybe instead of describing how poorly written my message is, you could shed some light and guide me, as the other user has done. On the other hand, the problem is already solved, after finding out about HAL I already have the drivers working and the sensors detected by the applications.